# run custom thread in custom service after destroy app

Tags: android, service, timer, background, thread-safety

I'm a few days, the problem with Android service.
I wrote custom Class from service
I wrote  custom class from thread.

I want my service to work after destroy program for send notification, everything is OK but custom class not working after destroy but in stop or pause app, my service work correct.
Please help me fix this problem.

ServiceNotification.class

```
import Threadcustom;

public class ServiceNotification extends Service {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    GlobalController.timerTaskService = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Threadcustom threadc = new Threadcustom();
          threadc.setDetail("1");
          threadc.start();
        Threadcustom threadc1 = new Threadcustom();
          threadc1.setDetail("2");
          threadc1.start();
        if (threadc.newMessage == 1) {
          CustomNotification customNotification = new CustomNotification();
          customNotification.notifiaction("my message");
        }
      }
    };
    GlobalController.timerService.schedule(GlobalController.timerTaskService, 0, 5000);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
      this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
      getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
      PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, restartServicePI);

  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
  }


  @Override
  public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
  }

}
```

manifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".services.ServiceBootCompleteReciver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name=".services.ServiceNotification"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    />
```

Threadcustom.class

```
public class ThreadSms extends Thread {
@Override
  public void run() {
    super.run();
       define my url
define http url connection get data from url then insert data to sqlite database in my application.

  }
```

my thread work correct my service work with thread and send notification,but after destroy app notification work but my custom thread not call, any program not crash only said warning

```
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/app.myapp/lib/arm
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/tcmclient.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624793/how-to-prevent-android-service-getting-killed-service-with-notification) 
you need a notification for your service if you don't want it being killed by OS 
also you can use timer to run/check your service is running or not . you can read this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434056/how-to-run-a-method-every-x-seconds) for implementing this method

Comment: does it work when screen locked or sleep .how can i do work on screen lock or sleep phone?????

Comment: @user3750973 yes it works while your notification is alive